# Substitution for hagelslag (chocolate sprinkles for bread)

Tags: substitutions, chocolate

I live in Spain but I am Dutch. Does anyone know a substitution for "hagelslag" (chocolate sprinkles to put on bread) for making boterhammen (open-faced sandwiches)?

[image: hagelslag / chcolate sprinkles]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hagelslag* is *[fideos de chocolate](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fideos_de_chocolate)* in Spanish, the coloured sprinkles are *fideos de colores*.

You should find it with the cake decorating stuff in at least the larger stores or online. (e.g. [here](http://www.pasteland.es/reposteria.aspx?categoria=3&producto=10) or [here](http://www.pasteland.es/reposteria.aspx?categoria=3&producto=11))

Comment: An expensive option. Another option is [Appie Hein](http://www.appiehein.com/es/pan-dulces-para-pan/2739-hagelslag-mix-ah-.html)

Comment: @BaffledCook just a random search result, not a recommendation. I trust OP shop wisely.